# Best way for handling a user/customer database for feedback

Tags: research, user-feedback, lean-ux, agile

For product of a certain size there are many people involved with research and feedback for each part/module of it. In addition, marketing and business people run their research as well.

Are there any best practices in documenting research and keeping research data that help balance the needs of each role and the user/customer?

Eg: Is the best practice to have one contact and notes space or separate lists that suit the need of each role? To keep notes? Or sum up, present, and trash notes.

Feel free to help me to make this question more specific - maybe it's too broad.

Answer (score 1):

The specifics will vary greatly depending on the software and system that you use, but some best practices include:

- **Keep the information in a central location accessible to the team(s) that will be using it.** Everyone who needs to access the research should be able to access it. Often, each team/group keeps their research to themselves, thinking that it wouldn't be relevant or useful to anyone else. As a result, information is hidden from people who need it.
- **Digest and understand the research.** Someone should analyze and interpret each body of research before it's shared. The raw data may also be made available, but someone with the right expertise should provide an interpretation.
- **Organize and prioritize the information.** Help others understand the research by giving it structure.They should be able to find answers to specific questions without reading the entire body of research. At the same time, it should be clear what research they *must* review in order to understand the project.